# I reinstalled metamask after formating my pc and tried to unlock Metamsk using 12 word phrase

Tags: metamask

I reinstalled metamask after formating my pc and tried to unlock Metamsk using 12 word phrase. but it's not getting unlocked and keep on working for long time (2-3hrs).  can somebody please tell me the reason and solution as well

Answer (score 1):

Did you get the seed phrase immediately before formatting your PC?

Recently there was an issue in Metamask, a bug in recovering from seed phrases in some cases which was recently resolved:

1) The bug:
https://medium.com/metamask/metamask-security-advisory-and-bug-bounty-for-seed-phrase-concern-bbd95ab63210

2) The fix:
https://medium.com/metamask/seed-phrase-issue-bounty-awarded-e1986e811021

Comment: Yes I've saved the seed phrase immediately after installing the extension before formatting my PC. After formatting my PC added extension and  tried to retrieve by clicking on 'Import  Existing DEN' and entering the seed phrase. but it's not working out..:( 
Does it take time to restore??